# Limiting the response of the MailChimp API to a new record on a list

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using the MailChimp API to create new records on a list after a form submission. However, currently, these requests can take up to 700ms according to New Relic to make. If this was a lookup, I'd limit the `fields` parameter to change what gets returned - I don't actually need anything other than a success/fail response - but there doesn't seem to be anything of that sort on the PUT list endpoint. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: By record, you mean a new contact/customer?

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne - yes, a new member of the list. :)